# reduce yAxis padding on highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

Is there any way to reduce the y? I'm using: http://www.highcharts.com/

[image: highcarts y padding]

Comment: Just reduce the height of the chart?

Comment: You can reduce your div's height, or use tickPixelInterval http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis.tickPixelInterval

Comment: and look at your maxPadding, and/or the endOnTick property